# Css 3 translate Z not working in Firefox

Tags: css, transformation, gsap

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TweenMax.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
var tl = new TimelineMax({ repeat:-1});
tl.to($('.box'), 10, {css:{transform:"translateZ(700px)"}});
tl.play();
</script>
```

translateZ working in chrome but not in Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `perspective` on your element or its parent for z-axis:

Working Example: http://codepen.io/jonathan/pen/HCfAi

```
// set perspective on parent which affects children
TweenLite.set("#wrapper", {perspective:1000});

// set transform perspective on element
TweenLite.set(".box", {transformPerspective:1000});
```

And you can also have GSAP add your CSS properties directly without using `transform` property.

```
var tl = new TimelineMax({repeat:-1});
// set perspective on element
tl.set($('.box'), {transformPerspective:1000});
tl.to($('.box'), 10, {css:{transform:"translateZ(700px)"}});
// translateZ could also be written like this
// tl.to($('.box'), 10, {css:{z:700}});
tl.play();
```

In GSAP CSS property equivalents (and camelCase):

- translateX() = **x**
- translateY() = **y**
- translateZ() = **z**
- rotateX() = **rotationX**
- rotateY() = **rotationY**
- rotateZ() = **rotation**
- perspective() = **perspective**
- transform: perspective() = **transformPerspective**

Reference GreenSock GSAP JS Forum (Thanks to Rodrigo):

http://greensock.com/forums/topic/10273-translatez-is-this-a-bug-in-chrome-and-firefox/